# Perl6 operator question

Tags: operators, raku

I was looking at the silly/cute/brilliant ["sleep sort" that seems to have originated over at 4chan](http://dis.4chan.org/read/prog/1295544154). To sort an array of ints, the idea is roughly

```
    
    foreach elt in @array
        spawn thread(elt)
```

where thread(n) does

```
    sleep n
    print n
```

so the smaller values get printed earlier.

There's a Perl6 implementation

```
@foo = @foo>>.&sleep;
```

I get that  `>>`  'hypers' the operator, and that this assumes hypering is automatically parallelized. But the `.&` confuses me.

Can anyone explain this?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a function `yourfunc`, then you can grab a reference to it with the ampersand, `&yourfunc`. The syntax `$obj.$function` just invokes `$function` with one argument, `$obj`. So one could just as well write `$function($obj)` - except that this syntax doesn't allow the use of a hyper.

But whoever came up with this "implementation" was wrong on three accounts:

- The hyper operator allows the compiler to spawn a number of threads for executing each method, it doesn't have to spawn a thread for all of them at once - so the "random sort" can't work
- The hyper operator may randomize the order of execution of the methods, but it has to preserve the order or the returned items - so `@foo` will not be sorted at all, even if the first point didn't apply.
- sleep() is supposed to return the number of seconds slept, not the argument. If somebody sets the computer to sleep during the calculation, the result might be a much higher number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, moritz. Two follow-ups: First, do you need the & to grab a reference (I think in C a function's name always returns a reference/pointer even without an &). And I thought '.' was "invoke method", i.e. search inheritance tree for appropriate class method. Is the use you describe some degenerate/default version of 'invoke method', or something else entirely?

Comment: Well, Perl 6 is not C. If you mention a subroutine without the ampersand, you call it.

Comment: Answering your second question: `$obj.method`is indeed a method call, but `$obj.$coderef` isn't.

Comment: @jonathan the name of the sleep function is `&sleep`, just as the name of the foo scalar is `$foo` and the name of the foo array is `@foo`.

Comment: See also Moritz's Xmas 2014 update on sleepsort in P6 at https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/webscale-sorting-of-the-sleepy-kind/